# Refactoring repetitive PHP properties to JS

Tags: javascript, php, refactoring

I was refactoring some old `PHP` code and there were some repetitive lines of code like this, which use the same properties:

```
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["total_streams"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["total_streams"];
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["total_listeners"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["total_listeners"];
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["source_of_stream"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["source_of_stream"];
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["access_type"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["access_type"];
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["metrics"]["new_collection_listeners"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["metrics"]["new_collection_listeners"];
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["metrics"]["spotify_playlist_placement"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["metrics"]["spotify_playlist_placement"];
$new_artist["spotify"]["current"]["date"] = $track["spotify"]["current"]["date"];
```

or

```
$new_artist["spotify_metadata"]["artist_followers"] = $track["spotify_metadata"]["artist_followers"];
$new_artist["spotify_metadata"]["artist_genres"] = $track["spotify_metadata"]["artist_genres"];
$new_artist["spotify_metadata"]["artist_popularity"] = $track["spotify_metadata"]["artist_popularity"];
$new_artist["spotify_metadata"]["artist_images"] = $track["spotify_metadata"]["artist_images"];
```

and I can refactor like:

```
const newArtist = new_artist["spotify"]["current"];
const spotifyCurrentData = track["spotify"]["current"];
newArtist["total_streams"] = spotifyCurrentData["total_streams"]
```

but I would need to create a new variable for every new property, was wondering does anyone some recommendations? I thought about just writing a function which takes in properties and extracts a value from a given array

Answer (score 0):

Why not just merge the arrays serverside and load that into your javascript?

```
$new_artist["spotify_metadata"] = array_merge(
    //Any original content
    $new_artist["spotify_metadata"],
    //Any new content from $track
    $track["spotify_metadata"]
)
```

In JavaScript you would have to loop over the keys and assign them:

```
var newArtist = new_artist["spotify"]["current"];
var spotifyCurrentData = track["spotify"]["current"];

for (const key in spotifyCurrentData) {
    if (spotifyCurrentData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newArtist[key] = spotifyCurrentData[key];
    }
}
```